# Project on a 3D model

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view, 2d

I have rendered an image from my 3D model and I do some processing on the image and now I add (lets say) a new point on the rendered image. Is it possible in any way to project this point from the rendered image back to the 3D model ?

Comment: Please be more precise with your question and how you imagine it

Comment: Do you mean you draw a point on the rendered image and want a vertex or something else in that point on the model?

Comment: @WhatAMesh I want to do something like @_mugnozzo_ mentioned. Lets say I have a 3D model of a cube and then I render one side of that cube into an image. Now I draw it´s centre on the image. How can I project that centre back to the 3D model of the cube. Remember this is just an example. My model is different.

Comment: Do you mean contructing 3d viewer from stack of images ??
https://quppler.com/creating-a-classifier-using-image-j-fiji-for-3d-volume-data-preparation-from-stack-of-images/